# How to retrieve the row with the max value only if it respect a criteria otherwise nothing should be returned

Tags: sql

The request searches for an object with a fixed 'id'. Only the row with the higher 'version' should be returned (last version). But no row at all should be returned if the higher version has 'deleted' column true.

Example:

```
|id    |version   |deleted |
|0     |1         |false   |
|0     |2         |false   |
|1     |1         |false   |
|1     |2         |false   |
|1     |3         |true    |
```

The request for id 0 should return

```
|1     |2         |false   |
```

But the request for id 1 should return nothing

I can do this with INTERSECT:

```
SELECT id, version, deleted FROM elements WHERE id = 1 AND deleted = 'false'
INTERSECT
SELECT id, MAX(version), deleted FROM elements WHERE id = 1
```

But is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: I assume that the request for `id` 0 should really return the second row:  `0, 2, false`.  Also, your code would return two rows for `id` 1 if the third version were not there.  However, you imply that you only want one row.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? That's going to affect the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to do this with a subquery:

```
select e.*
from (select id, version, deleted
      from elements
      where id = 1
      order by version desc
      limit 1
     ) e
where deleted = 'false';
```

This will return at most one row per `id`.  It will return the row with the highest version only if the `delete = 'false'`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using `Row_number()` functionality by ordering rows based on version and taking the one with the greatest version and using `WHERE` clause to ignore rows where `deleted <> false`

```
select id, version, deleted from (
select id, version, deleted, row_number() over 
(partition by id order by version desc) where deleted = 'false'
) A where rown = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with:

```
WITH src AS ( -- subquery gets the newest version for each of the ids
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (id)
        *
    FROM testtab 
    ORDER BY id, version DESC
)
SELECT * FROM SRC
WHERE NOT deleted -- or deleted = 'false' depending on it's type
    AND id = 0 -- your id goes here
```